# What does the caret (^) operator do?

Tags: python, operators, caret

I ran across the caret operator in python today and trying it out, I got the following output:

```
>>> 8^3
11
>>> 8^4
12
>>> 8^1
9
>>> 8^0
8
>>> 7^1
6
>>> 7^2
5
>>> 7^7
0
>>> 7^8
15
>>> 9^1
8
>>> 16^1
17
>>> 15^1
14
>>>
```

It seems to be based on 8, so I'm guessing some sort of byte operation?  I can't seem to find much about this searching sites other than it behaves oddly for floats, does anybody have a link to what this operator does or can you explain it here?

Comment: For integers, same thing it does in C. ^_-

Comment: FYI, from the python shell, you can type `help('^')`

Comment: -1: This is completely covered in the Python documentation and the included help function.  Asking this question here is silly.

Comment: Note that it doesn't behave oddly for floats (it just doesn't work with floats!). Also note that many people accidentally run into this while looking for `**`, the exponentiation operator.

Comment: @seth: `help('^')` does nothing in my Python 2.6.1 (apple build). @S.Lott: do you mean this  (http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) when you're saying "completely covered"?. Seems a bit sparse for someone unfamiliar with the concept...

Comment: @Mike Graham: that's actually where it came from.  I saw the ** operator and thought, well I wonder what caret does then, and here we are :)

Comment: @ChristopheD, No, he didn't mean that page, which is about parsing Python, not he semantics of what `^` does. `help('^')` in the interactive interpretter *should* pull up the help explaining the arithmetic operators, which would have provided only the name "bitwise XOR", which would have been enough information to go on.

Comment: I tried this in my interpreter (2.5.4) and got:
>>> help('^')                                                         
no Python documentation found for '^'

Answer (score 258, accepted):

It's a bitwise [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (exclusive OR).

It evaluates to `True` if and only if its arguments differ (one is `True`, the other is `False`).

To demonstrate:

```
>>> 0^0
0
>>> 1^1
0
>>> 1^0
1
>>> 0^1
1
```

To explain one of your own examples:

```
>>> 8^3
11
```

Think about it this way:

```
1000  # 8 (binary)
0011  # 3 (binary)
----  # APPLY XOR ('vertically')
1011  # result = 11 (binary)
```

Comment: A slightly more illustrative example might include both numbers having `1` in the same bit to make it clear that `1 xor 1 = 0`.

Comment: I wanted to add, you can do binary numbers by typing `0bX` where X is your binary. `0b0001`, `0b0010`, etc. So, `0b1101 ^ 0b1110` would give you `0b0011` (or 3).

Comment: I think "It results to true if one (and only one) of the operands (evaluates to) true." is not exact, it what would be the definition of a boolean xor

Answer (score 51):

It invokes the `__xor__()` or `__rxor__()` method of the object as needed, which for integer types does a bitwise exclusive-or.

Answer (score 16):

It's a bit-by-bit exclusive-or.  Binary bitwise operators are documented in [chapter 5 of the Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

Answer (score 13):

Generally speaking, the symbol `^` is an [infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) version of the `__xor__` or `__rxor__` methods. Whatever data types are placed to the right and left of the symbol must implement this function in a compatible way. For integers, it is the common `XOR` operation, but for example there is not a built-in definition of the function for type `float` with type `int`:

```
In [12]: 3 ^ 4
Out[12]: 7

In [13]: 3.3 ^ 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-858cc886783d> in <module>()
----> 1 3.3 ^ 4

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'
```

One neat thing about Python is that you can override this behavior in a class of your own. For example, in some languages the `^` symbol means exponentiation. You could do that this way, just as one example:

```
class Foo(float):
    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self ** other
```

Then something like this will work, and now, *for instances of `Foo` only*, the `^` symbol will mean exponentiation.

```
In [16]: x = Foo(3)

In [17]: x
Out[17]: 3.0

In [18]: x ^ 4
Out[18]: 81.0
```

Comment: woah, was that even possible? and could we probably change how the `+` operator works too?

Comment: Yes, this is how the `+` symbol is able to do one kind of action for `list` (concatenation) while doing another kind of action (mathematical addition) for numeric types. In that case, you would override the `__add__` or `__radd__` methods in your class.

Comment: As a side note, the `__r*__` version of these (like `__rxor__` or `__radd__`) will be invoked from the argument appearing on the *right hand side* of the infix symbol, and only if the call to the function for the left hand symbol doesn't work. You can think of it like `try: left_hand_symbol.__xor__(right_hand_symbol); except: right_hand_symbol.__rxor__(left_hand_symbol)`, but `xor` can be replaced by any of the available infix operators in the [Python Data Model](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=rlshift).

Comment: So that means I can craft my own operator which allows `int` concatenation with strings?  *man, python is way complex than I thought*

Comment: Side note, seeing as Python defines this as an xor operation and the method name has "xor" in it, I would consider it a poor design choice to make that method do something not related to xor like exponentiation. I think it's a good illustrative example of how it simply calls the `__xor__` method, but to do that for real would be bad practice.

Answer (score 8):

When you use the `^` operator, behind the curtains the method [**`__xor__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__xor__) is called.

`a^b` is equivalent to `a.__xor__(b)`.

Also, `a ^= b` is equivalent to `a = a.__ixor__(b)` (where `__xor__` is used as a fallback when `__ixor__` is implicitly called via using `^=` but does not exist).

In principle, what `__xor__` does is completely up to its implementation. Common use cases in Python are:

- **Symmetric Difference** of sets (all elements present in exactly one of two sets)

Demo:

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = {1, 4, 5}
>>> a^b
{2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> a.symmetric_difference(b)
{2, 3, 4, 5}
```

- **Bitwise Non-Equal** for the bits of two integers

Demo:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 6
>>> a^b
3
```

Explanation:

```
    101 (5 decimal)
XOR 110 (6 decimal)
-------------------
    011 (3 decimal)
```