# Plotting graph from Physics formula (no data files), python and numpy

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I keep having the following error in my code:

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'"
```

I tried doing `//` in formula to get rid of floats but it didn't work. I'm trying to graph a function `V(ru)`. I don't know any bounds except `V` has to start after `0`. The one thing I am not sure about is the `linspace` and `x` and `y` limits. Can someone tell me if my error is related to those lines and if not which line?
Also does anyone know why even if it shows up its a simple linear graph?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

r_data = numpy.linspace(1, 50)

def V(ru):
    rm = 2**(1/6)
    return ((rm/ru)**0.5)-(2*((rm/ru)^6))

v_data = numpy.linspace(V(1), v(50))

plt.plot(r_data, v_data)
plt.xlim(1, 50)
plt.ylim(V(1), V(50))
```

Comment: The caret `^` is the XOR operator in Python.  You probably want `**` for exponentiation.  Try: `return ((rm/ru)**0.5)-(2*((rm/ru)**6))`

Comment: Your issue appears to be in the return statement `((rm/ru)**0.5)-(2*((rm/ru)^6))` the `^` should be changed to `**`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the caret operator (^) in Python do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two typos: *First*: `^` instead of `**` because in python the latter is used for raising powers and *Second*, `v` instead of `V`. The lines modified have been marked by a hashtag `#`. The errors you got had nothing to do with `xlim` or `ylim` but the syntax.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

r_data = numpy.linspace(1, 50)

def V(ru):
    rm = 2**(1/6)
    return ((rm/ru)**0.5)-(2*((rm/ru)**6)) # ^ replaced by **

v_data = numpy.linspace(V(1), V(50)) # v(50) replaced by V(50)

plt.plot(r_data, v_data)
plt.xlim(1, 50)
plt.ylim(V(1), V(50))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Crazy how it's still easy to overlook little mistakes like that in the code. It works now

Comment: Idk if you get notifications for these comments, but do you think my linspace is why its linear? Because the function technically shouldn't be

Comment: The linspace is always linear

Comment: @LilyBateman you need to use the linespace as the domain for your function, V. So, basically, you want: `plt.plot(r_data, V(r_data))` and this: `plt.ylim(V(1), V(50))` is not going to work. You want something like `V(r_data).max() + 0.5` or whatever...