# Change 1's to 0 and 0's to 1 in numpy array without looping

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array where I would like to swap all the 1's to 0 and all the 0's to 1 (the array will have other values, and there is nothing special about the 0's and 1's). Of course, I can loop through the array and change the values one by one.

Is there an efficient method you can recommend using? Does the `np.where()` method have an option for this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way which does not require the use of any special method such as `np.where()` is to get the indices for the conditions of the variables in your `numpy` array, and accordingly assign the required value (in your case `0` for `1s` and `1` for `0s`) to the respective positional items in the array. This works for values other than `0s` and `1s` too. Also, you don't require any temporary variable to swap the values.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 1, 0])
indices_one = arr == 1
indices_zero = arr == 0
arr[indices_one] = 0 # replacing 1s with 0s
arr[indices_zero] = 1 # replacing 0s with 1s

Output: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Note to readers: much better (faster and more general) solutions below

Answer (score 26):

Here's one way using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), and taking the bitwise `XOR` of a given value when it is either `0` or `1`:

```
np.where((a==0)|(a==1), a^1, a)
```

---

For example:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2,1], [1,2,0,3]])
print(a)
array([[0, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 0, 3]])

np.where((a==0)|(a==1), a^1, a)

array([[1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 3]])
```

Comment: `a^1` that was super clever :-)

Comment: Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do for those (like me!) who don't know what `^` does...

Comment: You can equally use `1-a`, by the way.

Comment: If the array is unsigned integers, your 2 tests could probably be made simpler/faster with the single test `a<2`, also by the way ;-)

Comment: Yes, in such case it would be a nice simplification :) @MarkSetchell

Comment: From my test, the most optimized way is not this answer. See other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56596332/11671779). Benchmark see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479579/11671779).

Answer (score 9):

This is a less clever option with np.where, just using it for indexing:

```
where_0 = np.where(arr == 0)
where_1 = np.where(arr == 1)

arr[where_0] = 1
arr[where_1] = 0
```

If you know more about the other values (e.g. they're all small numbers) there may be more options, but this is simplest.

Comment: Perhaps other than using twice `np.where` you could use `np.select`?

Answer (score 9):

```
a^(a&1==a)
```

for example

```
a = np.arange(-3, 4)
a^(a&1==a)
# array([-3, -2, -1,  1,  0,  2,  3])
```

Comment: Ha! Well this is neat! Had to run myself to understand what `(a&1==a)` does here :)

Comment: @yatu yeah, there can't be too many people who know the operator precedence here. I certainly had to go by trial and error ;-]

Comment: I like this.  I always prefer calculating a result to if / else.

Comment: Awesome! Probably not the most semantic but definitely the most optimized.

Comment: The best way to go. Please upvote this answer. Benchmark see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479579/11671779)

Answer (score 2):

`iverted = ~arr + 2`  should do the work

Comment: Be aware that this answer can't handle `the array will have other values`. For example, `4` will be `-3`.

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part is `the array will have other values`. In case only 0 and 1 (no other value), `arr = ~arr + 2` is the fastest way. If `the array will have other values` needs to be considered, use `arr^(arr&1==arr)`. Here is the benchmark.

```py
%%timeit

np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

arr = ~arr + 2
```

```
38.8 µs ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit

np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

where_1 = arr == 1
where_0 = arr == 0

arr[where_1] = 0 # replacing 1s with 0s
arr[where_0] = 1 # replacing 0s with 1s
```

```
45.2 µs ± 7.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit

np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

arr = arr^(arr&1==arr)
```

```
40.3 µs ± 7.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit

np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

where_1 = np.where(arr == 1)
where_0 = np.where(arr == 0)

arr[where_0] = 1
arr[where_1] = 0
```

```
49.1 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit

np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

arr = np.where((arr==0)|(arr==1), arr^1, arr)
```

```
52.3 µs ± 11.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

`inverted = ~arr + 2`, did the trick for me as my array was of 8 bits

The '~' operator flips all the bits of the integer in the array from 0 to 1 and vice versa. For example, if you have the integer 0 represented by eight bits (one byte) 0000 0000, the tilde operation ~0000 0000 results in the value 1111 1111 which is the integer value -1, [*reference*](https://blog.finxter.com/tilde-python/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20Tilde%20%7E%20in,1%20and%20%7E101%20becomes%20010%20.)

so if a = 0, ~a gives -1 and (~a+2) gives 1
and if a = 1, ~a gives -2 and (~a+2) gives 0