# How to multiply numbers of a string by its position in the string

Tags: string, binary, decode, multiplication

I am a newby on this. I am trying to multiply every single element of the string below ('10010010') by 2 to the power of the position of the element in the string and sum all the multiplications. So far I am trying to do it like this, but I cannot achieve to figure out how to do it.

def decodingvalue(str1):

```
# read each character in input string 
for ch in str1: 
    q=sum(2^(ch-1)*ch.isdigit())
return q
```

## Function call

print(decodingvalue('10010010'))

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) -- [tag:python] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Comment: Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you trying convert binary to int. If that so you can do the following:

```
str = '101110101'
#length is counted 1 to n, decrementing by 1 changes to 0-(n-1)
c = len(str)-1 
q = 0
for ch in str:
    print(q,c,ch)
    q = q + (int(ch)*(2**c)) #in python power is '**'
    c = c-1
    if c == -1:
        break

print(q)
```

you can of course optimize it and finish in fewer lines.
In python ^ (caret operator) is a [Bitwise XOR.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do)