# My while loop executes but the output is not expected. Why?

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and I wrote the following code:

```
print("This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.")
num = int(input("Enter a number to square, cube, etc. : "))

i = 0

while i<10:
    numpow = 1
    c = num^ numpow
    print(f"{num} to the power of {numpow} is {c}")
    numpow = 1 + numpow
    i += 1
```

And output is:

```
This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.
Enter a number to square, cube, etc. : 3
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
3 to the power of 1 is 2
```

but this is not the expected output. I want the output as given:

```
This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.
Enter a number to square, cube, etc. : 3
3 to the power of 1 is 3
3 to the power of 2 is 9
3 to the power of 3 is 27
3 to the power of 4 is 81
3 to the power of 5 is 243
3 to the power of 6 is 729
3 to the power of 7 is 2187
3 to the power of 8 is 6561
3 to the power of 9 is 19683
3 to the power of 10 is 59049
```

WHY?

Since you know I am a beginner I sat to work on it for 1/2 hours but didn't got the solution. I am tired of it.

Comment: `^` this is XOR operator in python, use `**` for power

Comment: Ohh! I did not even knew that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW what is XOR operator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do

Comment: You can learn about them here [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bitwise-operators/)

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few problems in code:

- The power is calculate with `**` or the `pow()` function
- numpow is an unnecessary variable since you have the index

The code after a those changes:

```
print("This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.")
num = int(input("Enter a number to square, cube, etc. : "))

i = 1
while i <= 10:
    c = pow(num, i)
    print(f"{num} to the power of {i} is {c}")
    i += 1
```

**Input**

```
3
```

**Output**

Before the input:

```
This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.
Enter a number to square, cube, etc. :
```

After input:

```
3 to the power of 1 is 3
3 to the power of 2 is 9
3 to the power of 3 is 27
3 to the power of 4 is 81
3 to the power of 5 is 243
3 to the power of 6 is 729
3 to the power of 7 is 2187
3 to the power of 8 is 6561
3 to the power of 9 is 19683
3 to the power of 10 is 59049
```

Comment: But at the third line of the code which is 

```
to the power of 1 is 3
```

Why does the 3 do not print?

Comment: Is printed, i'll add the input and the output to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two errors in your code, you will notice it in the code below:

```
i = 0

while i<10:
    numpow = i
    c = num** numpow
    print(f"{num} to the power of {numpow} is {c}")
    i += 1
```

Comment: This code gives the wrong output, you are using the XOR operator `^` instead of power  `**` here.

Comment: Thak you very much @Abhi_J I forgot to edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while i<10:
    numpow = 1
```

For each iteration you assign numpow to 1.
to fix the bug please change it to:

```
numpow = 1
while i<10:
```

Also seems you need to use ** instead of ^

Comment: How will that resolve the iteration loop

Comment: because after print line he/she wrote "numpow = 1 + numpow"

Answer (score 1):

just for fun check this out too :

```
print("This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.")
num = int(input("Enter a number to square, cube, etc. : "))

for numpow in range(1,11):
    c = num**numpow
    print(f"{num} to the power of {numpow} is {c}")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need your variable outside the `while` loop or it will evaluate it as one all the time. and use `**` as power of.

```
print("This is a program to print squares, cubes, etc. table.")
num = int(input("Enter a number to square, cube, etc. : "))

i = 0
numpow = 1
while i<10:
    
    c = num ** numpow
    print("{0} to the power of {1} is {2}".format(num, numpow, c))
    i += 1
    numpow += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
i = 0

while i<10:
    numpow = 1
    c = num** numpow
    print(f"{num} to the power of {numpow} is {c}")
    numpow = 1 + numpow
    i += 1
```

Comment: you still have a bug