# Count Sign Change

Tags: python, math

I have this array:

```
X = [0,2,-1,2,1,2]
```

And the sign changes two times (0 is positive here).

Example:

2 to -1 (first time)

-1 to 2 (second times)

```
last_sign = 1
sign_changes = 0

for x in X:
    if x == 0:
        sign = -1
    else:
        sign = x / abs(x)

    if sign == -last_sign:
        sign_changes = sign_changes + 1
        last_sign = sign

print(sign_changes)
```

But when I print the result I get 4. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike what you described, you are assigning negative sign to zero: note that you put `sign = -1` at `if x == 0:`. This is the culprit here. (Also your current code assumes that the list starts with a non-negative number. A list starting with a negative number won't produce an expected outcome.)

You can try instead:

```py
X = [0,2,-1,2,1,2]

print(sum((a >= 0) != (b >= 0) for a, b in zip(X, X[1:]))) # 2
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion, iterate pairwise and check if the pairs have different signs:

```
from itertools import tee


def pairwise(iterable):
    # pairwise('ABCDEFG') --> AB BC CD DE EF FG
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


X = [0, 2, -1, 2, 1, 2]

res = sum((before < 0) ^ (after < 0) for before, after in pairwise(X))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

As an alternative, without any libraries, use:

```
res = sum((before < 0) ^ (after < 0) for before, after in zip(X, X[1:]))
```

The expression:

```
(before < 0) ^ (after < 0)
```

is an [exclusive or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do), it will only be True (1) if the boolean values are different.

Comment: I am not allowed to import frameworks :/

Comment: @bot_der_4 Updated the answer.

Comment: It works with the Array I mentioned but not with other Arrays like X = [2, -1, 0, -1, 1, 2]...

Comment: @bot_der_4 Updated the answer, changed the way to check for sign