# ^ operator in numpy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am not able to understand what is ^ operator in NumPy array with boolean values.

```
print("----------train_mask before-------------------------------------------")
print (train_mask[10:30])
print(len(train_mask))
train_mask ^= eval_mask
print("----------eval -------------------------------------------")
print (eval_mask[10:30])
print(len(eval_mask))
print("----------train_mask -------------------------------------------")
print (train_mask[10:30])
print(len(train_mask))
```

output is:

[image]

I am not able to understand how that True value is converted to False

Comment: Seems like XOR from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-do

Comment: Can you turn this into a working example - initialize an array with test data so that we can run it too.

Answer (score 1):

[`^` is the bitwise XOR operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=xor#binary-bitwise-operations) in Python as others have said.

Check out the documentation for [`numpy.bitwise_xor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html#numpy.bitwise_xor), which reads in part:

> Compute the bit-wise XOR of two arrays element-wise.

The key point here is [“element-wise,”](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html?highlight=element%20wise) so in your example, since there’s one only one `True` value in your `eval_mask` array, only one value is changed in the output.

It is the same as (for these simple 1d arrays):

```
>>> a = [True, True]
>>> b = [True, False]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...      a[i] ^= b[i]
... 
>>> a
[False, True]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([True, True])
>>> y = np.array([True, False])
>>> x ^ y
array([False,  True])
```